# Multiple tables join via Spring JdbcTemplate returns an empty result

Tags: java, sql, spring-jdbc

Trying to join 3 tables within a query returns an empty result. Strange enough, having one table removed (two tables join) returns some set. Here is what I do:

```
    String sql = "SELECT\n" +
            "    tc.constraint_name, tc.table_name, kcu.column_name, \n" +
            "    ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,\n" +
            "    ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name, constraint_type \n" +
            "FROM \n" +
            "    information_schema.table_constraints AS tc \n" +
            "    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu\n" +
            "      ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name\n" +
            "    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu\n" +
            "      ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name\n" +
            "WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'";
    List<Map<String, Object>> foreignTable1 = jdbcTemplate(getShardId(sku)).queryForList(sql);
```

Would always return an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

Try using outer joins and check whether there are rows which don't have corresponding IDs so that the join removes the non-matching rows. Especially that you write, that two tables result in a non-empty result set seems to indicate, that the join with the third table does not result in matching rows of the result set of the first two.

Comment: I have also used outer SELECT * from information_schema.table_constraints, information_schema.key_column_usage, information_schema.constraint_column_usage. the same empty result. but only 2 tables return something

Comment: I would just quickly change the second join to "OUTER JOIN" to check whether there are simply no matching rows for the result set of the first join.

Comment: SELECT * from information_schema.table_constraints, information_schema.key_column_usage, information_schema.constraint_column_usage -- would produce a cartesian w/o matching!

Comment: You should remove the _java_ and _jdbc_ tags as this has nothing to do with spring or java and has only to do with your SQL. Honestly without looking at your table relations and data you are going to have to test and see. Try removing your constraints (WHERE), then add in tables one at a time to make sure you are getting correct results. Joining your tables simply limits what results you get back. Without looking at your tables myself, there is nothing else to go on. Try running your SQL outside of java in a SQL testing application if that is available to you -- Good luck